# Backgroundimage after first compiling at wrong position

Tags: pdftex, texlive, backgrounds

I am using TexLive and I have a problem with setting up a background image. My code looks like following:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[]{background}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}

\backgroundsetup{
    scale=1,
    color=black,
    opacity=0.9,
    angle=0,
    placement=bottom,
    nodeanchor=south,
    vshift=2cm,
    contents={%
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4in]{background-image.png}
        }%
}


\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

When I compile the .tex file via `pdflatex test.tex` the image's position is on top of the paper and only a small part of it is visible. After recompiling the PDF: the image's position is at the bottom of the page with some bottom margin, so it is correct.

I don't know why I have to compile the same file twice to get the correct result. Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for help!

Comment: you are doing nothing wrong. background uses tikz and page nodes and they need two compilations. You could use eso-pic or with a new latex the shipout/background hook instead. That would work directly.

Comment: side remark: don't use the ngerman package, that is certainly wrong. use `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`  instead.

Comment: Thank you,  @UlrikeFischer. Do you have an example how to use the shipout/background?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/591272/2388

Comment: Thank you so much!